# trying to clean a phone number so that if it is entered like 816-345-6757 it would return it like 8163456757

Tags: javascript

I am trying to clean a phone number so that if it is entered like 816-345-6757 or 816-+456-6775 it would clean it up by removing the dash and plus sign or spaces and return 8164566775. I am a newbie and I feel like i am running into a problem.

//finish the line of code below so that any dashes-, spaces, commas, plus signs+, parenthesis(), are globally removed:

```
var regex = "-+,()";
regex = regex.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

Comment: Just do a regex for all non numerical characters..

Comment: could you give me an example? @wateriswet

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple regex with some example script.

```
var phoneNumber = "!@()#20312@32912#(HFSDWER";
var cleanNumber = phoneNumber.replace(/([^0-9])/g,'');
```

It should output: 2031232912